# How to map data with one-to-many relationship in spring JDBC?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I would like to ask for suggestions from all of you guys, which is the best choice to fetch data with **ONE TO MANY** relationship using Spring JDBC? I decide to use Spring JDBC because I have a complex query.

Ex: I have two tables which are student and subject. A student can study many subjects. So, I will join these tables using one-to-many relationships.

1. Join level DB: I can join on the level database but I need to map on level by code using loop then add subjects as a list of student objects.
2. Call separate query, One for student and using **student_id** to find in subjects table

what do you think, please give me the advice?
Thank you!

Comment: Please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461735/jdbc-template-one-to-many